# Cs scripting using in to Silverlight project

Tags: c#, silverlight-5.0

I want to use [CS-Script](http://www.csscript.net/) in to a **Silverlight** project,

we have to validate some of fields base on the script file if it's valid then send data to save other wise display message according to field.

we are using WCF for data transfer

Comment: And your question is? What did you try?

Comment: You also got an answer here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/silverlightgen/thread/bf17e69e-a37f-4631-8edc-7724243c423a